# Panel DefaultButton doesn't work in Safari

Tags: c#, asp.net, safari

I have a basic login form, and I want the form to be submitted when the user presses Enter

```
<asp:Panel ID="pnlLogin" runat="server" DefaultButton="lbLogin">
    <asp:TextBox ID="txtUsername" runat="server" />
    <asp:TextBox ID="txtPassword" runat="server" TextMode="Password" />
    <asp:LinkButton ID="lbLogin" runat="server" onclick="lbLogin_Click" />
</asp:Panel>
```

This works in IE, Firefox, and Chrome, but not in Safari. Anyone know how I can get that LinkButton clicked when I push Enter in Safari?

Comment: Which version of Safari please? It certainly works in one of my apps. Also what version .net are you using.

Comment: @Constanta - Version 5.1.7

Comment: My apologies, I didn't realise you are using a Linkbutton. I just tried your code and it doesn't work for me either so please disregard my previous comment. Maybe there's a javascript solution or you can swap your Linkbutton for a Button or ImageButton?